# The number of elements of order $p$ in a $p$-group is $-1 \bmod p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading a proof and it takes the following statement - but it is not immediate to me why it is true at all:

> The number of elements of order $p$ ($p$ prime) in a $p$-group is $-1 \bmod p$.

Comment: Hint: You may have seen that the number of solutions of $x^{p} = 1_{G}$ in $G$ is divisible by $p$ whenever $|G|$ is divisible by $p$ when $p$ is prime ( in fact, the statement is true for any positive integer $p$, though the case $p$ is prime is the one that is relevant here).

Comment: Oh, okay, yes, I can see that the solution of $x^p = 1$ forms a group hence divides $p^k$, the order of the $p$-group. And all the solutions is an element of order $p$ except the identity, QED? @GeoffRobinson, thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's a bit more subtle here: the solutions of $x^{p}=1$ do not necessarily form a subgroup. The result I was thinking of (or at least the easiest proof) is due to McKay. However, in the $p$-group case, it's easier to check. I could give more hints, but ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clarification of McKay's Proof of Cauchy's Theorem for Groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238385/clarification-of-mckays-proof-of-cauchys-theorem-for-groups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the group is abelian, then $a \to a^p$ is a homomorphism and the order of the kernel is a power of $p$ - as a subgroup of a $p$-group. however this kernel consists of the identity and all the elements of order $p$, hence the number of the latter is congruent to $-1 (\mod p)$.

since any $p$-group has a non-trivial center, the required result follows if it can be shown that the number of non-central elements of order $p$ is a multiple of $p$. but this follows by considering conjugacy classes, since every centralizer has order a positive power of $p$.

Comment: Hi David, thanks. I understand that every centralizer has order a positive power of p, but why this implies nonabelian groups has -1 mod p elements of order p?

Comment: the size of the orbit (under the action of the full group of inner automorphisms) of a non-central element is equal to the index of its centralizer, which is a multiple of $p$ (in fact a power of $p$). because $a^x = a^y$ if and only if $x^{-1}ax=y^{-1}ay$ or $yx^{-1}a = a yx^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks for yor clarification. But I still didn't see -1 mod p order p elements coming out?

Comment: that comes from the center, as mentioned in the first part of the answer. in a $p$-group every conjugacy class has either a multiple of $p$ elements, or is a singleton. the singletons are the central elements, one of which is the identity./

Comment: But why it happens to be 1 singleton? If the center has c elements, then shouldn't it be -c mod p?

Comment: $\#\{g\in G:|g|=p\}
=\#\{g\in Z(G):|g|=p\}+\#\{g\notin Z(G):|g|=p\}
\stackrel{Z(G)\text{ is abelian}}{=}pk-1+\#\{g\notin Z(G):|g|=p\}
\stackrel{|g|=p, ~|aga^{-1}|=p, ~\forall b\in \text{orbit}(g), ~|b|=p}{=}
=pk-1+|\text{orbit}(g_1)|+|\text{orbit}(g_2)|+\cdots +|\text{orbit}(g_m)|
=pk-1+\sum_{i=1}^{m}[G:C(g_i)]=pk-1+\sum_{i=1}^{m}p^{r_i}$,
where $|\text{orbit}(g_i)|\neq 1$, $\text{orbit}(g_i)\cap \text{orbit}(g_j)=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$, $|g_i|=p$, $r_i\geq 1$.

Comment: @1LiterTears Any element of order $p$ is either in the center or not. The number of elements of order $p$ in the center is $-1 \pmod p$ by the abelian group argument. The number of elements of order $p$ not in the center is $0 \pmod p$, by the conjugacy class argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method.

Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $X=\{g\in G\mid |g|=p\}$ be the set of all the elements of order $p$.
Let $G$ act on $X$ by conjugation.
Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
&& |orbit(x)|=1\\
&\Leftrightarrow& orbit(x)=\{x\}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& \{g\cdot x=gxg^{-1}\mid g\in G\}=\{x\}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& \forall g\in G, ~gxg^{-1}=x\\
&\Leftrightarrow& x\in Z(G).
\end{eqnarray*}
Then by the class equation,
\begin{eqnarray*}
|X|
&=&\sum_{\substack{x\in X\\|orbit(x)|=1}}|orbit(x)|+\sum_{\substack{i=1\\ |orbit(x_i)|\neq 1\\ orbit(x_i)\neq orbit(x_j)\text{ if }i\neq j}}^{n}|orbit(x_i)|\\
&=&\sum_{\substack{x\in X\\ x\in Z(G)}}1+\sum_{\substack{i=1\\ [G:stab(x_i)]\neq 1}}^{n}[G:stab(x_i)]\\
&=& |Z(G)\cap X|+\sum_{\substack{i=1\\ [G:stab(x_i)]\neq 1}}^{n}[G:stab(x_i)].
\end{eqnarray*}
Then $$p\text{ divides }\sum_{\substack{i=1\\ [G:stab(x_i)]\neq 1}}^{n}[G:stab(x_i)]=|X|-|Z(G)\cap X|$$
(because $H$ is a $p$-group)
and
$$|X|\equiv |Z(G)\cap X|\pmod{p}.$$

(Tricky.) Verify that $(Z(G)\cap X)\cup \{e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
Then by Lagrange's Theorem and $e\notin Z(G)\cap X$, 
$|Z(G)\cap X|+1=|(Z(G)\cap X)\cup \{e\}|$ divides $|G|$.
It follows that $$|Z(G)\cap X|\equiv -1\pmod{p}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This question is from Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups* 4/e, p.75, Lemma 4.7
or Isaacs's *Finite Group Theory*, p.7, 1A.8.(b).
There is another exercise in Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* 8/e.
Which is essentially the same as this problem.
See exercise 24.59.
Here is the author's proof.

**Corollary of Theorem 4.4.** Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=n$.
If $d\mid n$, 
then the number of elements of order $d$ is $\phi(d)k$ for some $k\in \Bbb{Z}$, 
where $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function.

We prove your assertion.
Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $|G|=p^n$.
By Lagrange's Theorem, 
the order of every element in $G$ is a power of $p$.
Thus, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\#\{g\in G:|g|=p\}
&=&|G|-\#\{g\in G:|g|=p^n\}-\#\{g\in G:|g|=p^{n-1}\}\\
&-&\cdots -\#\{g\in G:|g|=p^2\}-\#\{g\in G:|g|=1\}\\
&=&p^n-\phi(p^n)k_n-\phi(p^{n-1})k_{n-1}-\cdots -\phi(p^2)k_2-1\\
&=&ps-1.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Exercise 24.59.** 
Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime that divides $|G|$.
Let $n$ denote the number of elements of $G$ that have order $p$. 
If the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is normal, 
prove that $p$ divides $n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proof.
The idea was obtained by plenty observations.

Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $|G|=p^n$.
By the exercise II.5.3 in Hungerford's *Algebra*, 
there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of order $p$ in $G$.

If $N\neq H\leq G$ and $|H|=p$,
that is, $H$ is another subgroup of order $p$,
verify that the set $S=\{hN\mid h\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G/N$.
By Correspondence Theorem,
there exists $K$ such that $N\leq K$ and $K/N=S$.
Note that $|K/N|=|S|=p$ and $|K|=p^2$.
By the exercise II.5.13 in Hungerford's *Algebra*,
$K$ is abelian.
Write $K/N=\langle kN\rangle$,
where $k\notin N$.

Since
$$\langle kn_i\rangle/N
\ni(kn_i)^mN
\stackrel{K\text{ is abelian}}{=}k^m n_i^mN
=k^m N
=(kN)^m
\in \langle kN\rangle
=K/N,
$$
we have $\langle kn_i\rangle/N=K/N$ for each $n_i\in N=\{n_1, n_2, ...,n_p\}$.
Note that $|\langle kn_i\rangle/N|=|K/N|=p$.
So $\langle kn_i\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p$.
Hence,
$\langle kn_1\rangle, \langle kn_2\rangle, ..., \langle kn_p\rangle$
are all distinct subgroups of $G$ whose order is $p$
such that $\langle kn_i\rangle/N=K/N$.
The $p$ subgroups $\langle kn_1\rangle, \langle kn_2\rangle, ..., \langle kn_p\rangle$ of $G$ correspond to a same subgroup $K$.

Similarly,
except $N$,
every $p$ subgroups of order $p$ in $G$ correspond to a same subgroup of order $p^2$.
Let $s$ be the number of subgroups of order $p$ in $G$.
Then $p\mid (s-1)$.
Let $r$ be the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$.
Note that
$s=\frac{r}{p-1}$,
as the following figure indicates.

[image]

Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
p\mid (s-1)=\left(\frac{r}{p-1}-1\right)
&\Rightarrow& p(p-1)\mid r-(p-1)\\
&\Rightarrow& p\mid r-p+1\\
&\Rightarrow& p\mid r+1
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as a corollary of the more general following:

**Theorem**. Let $p$ be a prime, $G$ a group of order $|G|=p^\alpha m$, where $\alpha\ge 1$ and $p\nmid m$. Denoted with $n_k:=\#$ of subgroups of order $p^k$, we get:
$$n_k\equiv 1\pmod p$$
for every $k=1,\dots,\alpha$.

*Proof*: see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4494783/1092170).

**Corollary.** For $k=1$, the Theorem states that the number of subgroups of order $p$ is $n_1=lp+1$ for some nonnegative integer $l$. Each of them comprises $p-1$ elements of order $p$, which therefore are overall $N=(p-1)(lp+1)\equiv$ $-1\pmod p$.