# For the set $X=\{g\in G:g^p=1\}$, show that $p$ divides $|X|$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime divisor of $|G|$. Consider the set $X=\{g\in G:g^p=1\}$. Show that $p$ divides $|X|$.

**My attempt:** Consider the action of $G$ on $X$ by conjugation. Then ${\rm Stab}_g=C_G(g)$ for all $g\in X$. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/238424/1070376

Comment: So this looks like a rather difficult problem.   And the result is attributed to McKay.

Comment: Just a remark. Frobenius has proved that if $n$ divides the order of a group $G$, then the number of elements whose $n$-th power is $1$ is a multiple of $n$.

Comment: There is a nice proof of Frobenius' theorem here https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324902#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: @Cpc: Would you mind making a short answer out of your comment? (This question is not a strict duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/238385/61691, so we should make sure that it does not stay in open but unanswered state.)

Comment: Well,  @azimut, the problem is solved in the answer linked above.   What should I say?

Comment: @Cpc it completely agree. But technically, a comment is not an answer in the stackexchange mechanism, so this question counts as unanswered. So it would be great if you could formulate your comment as a short "real" answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X$ comprises all and only the elements of $G$ of order $p$, plus the identity. Such elements are grouped in $m$ trivially intersecting subgroups each of order $p$. Therefore:
\begin{alignat}{1}
|X| &= m(p-1)+1 \\
&=mp-(m-1) \\
\tag1
\end{alignat}
But $m\equiv 1\pmod p$, because the number $n_k$ of subgroups of $G$ of order $p^k$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ *for every* $k=0,1,\dots,k_{\text{max}}$ (see *e.g.* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4494783/1007416)), and in particular for $k=1$. Therefore, $m=n_1\equiv 1\pmod p$, and hence from $(1)$ $p\mid |X|$.

Comment: What does the phrase "arraied in $m$, trivially intersecting subgroups" mean?

Comment: By Lagrange, two subgroups of order $p$ either coincide or trivially intersect, @Guest. And all the nontrivial elements of a subgroup of order $p$ have order $p$.

Comment: Yes, I know. But what is the meaning of "arraied"?

Comment: I meant "are placed in".

Comment: So these subgroups are placed in an integer?

Comment: Think of a flower: each petal is a subgroup of order $p$, and each petal touch any other in center of the flower (the identity), only. Each petal comprises $p-1$ elements (each of order $p$), plus the identity; and there are $m$ petals.

Comment: Oh, the comma after $m$ is what caused the entire confusion!

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are right it may be confusing... I'm used in that when there are multiple adjectives referring to one same noun.

Comment: Comma removed now.

Comment: I corrected the spelling of 'arrayed', which might have been throwing some people off.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidA.Craven. Thanks to MSE, I'm learning probably as much English as math!

Comment: @fitzcarraldo I maybe would use 'grouped' because 'arrayed' usually would mean set out in rows and columns, like a matrix, a table, or an old-fashioned army.

Comment: Good, edited accordingly.